# Why does the Galton-Watson Process dies out a.s. when the mean is less than 1?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

The following image describes a Galton-Watson process.

> Let $\xi_i^n$, $i,n\geq1$, be i.i.d. nonnegative integer-valued random variables. Define a sequence $Z_n$, $n\geq0$ by $Z_0=1$ and
> $$Z_{n+1}=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
> \xi_1^{n+1}+\cdots+\xi_{Z_n}^{n+1} & \text{if} & Z_n>0,\\
> 0 & \text{if} & Z_n=0.
> \end{array}\right.$$

This is the Galton-Watson Process where the $Z_n$ term is supposed to represent the number of individuals in the $n^{th}$ generation.

If $\mu:=E[\xi_i^m]<1$ then $Z_n$ is $0$ a.s. for $n$ large enough. However, I do not understand the proof which goes as follows:

1. $\frac{Z_n}{\mu^n}$ is a martingale. (This is fine.)
2. Since $E[\frac{Z_n}{\mu^n}]=E[X_0]=1$ this implies that $E[Z^n]=\mu^n$. Also $Z_n1_{\{Z_n>0\}}\geq 1_{\{Z_n>0\}}$ which implies that:$$P(Z_n>0)\leq E[Z_n;Z_n>0]\leq E[Z_n]=\mu^n\rightarrow 0.$$

The proof ends there. However, I don't see why this shows that $Z_n=0$ for large enough $n$. It just shows that for large enough $n$, $P(Z_n>0)$ is really small but it might not be zero which is what we want since almost surely requires $P(Z_n=0)=1$ for large enough $n$.

Any ideas how one might complete the proof?

Answer (score 1):

$Z_n=0$ implies $Z_{n+1}=0$. Let $E_n$ be the event $Z_n=0$. Then $P(Z_n=0 \text  { for some } n)=P(\bigcup_n E_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty} P(E_n)$ since $E_n$'s are increasing. Hence,$P(Z_n=0 \text  { for some } n)=1$.

Comment: Im sorry could you explain why $P(Z_n=0 \text{ for some n })=P(\cup_n E_n)$. I don't see why those events are the same. i.e. if $\omega \in \cup_n E_n$ then there exits $N$ s.t for all $n\geq N$ $Z_n(\omega)=0$. But this $N$ changes for each $\omega$. So how do we show there exists a uniform $N$ for each $\omega$?

Comment: I defined  $E_n$  as $(Z_n=0)$. So $P(Z_n=0 \text  { for some } n)=P(\bigcup_n E_n)$ That is the definition of union of sets. @JhonDoe

Comment: I view $E_n:=\{Z_n=0\}=Z_n^{-1}\{0\}$ is this what you meant? I am sorry I am new to this probability stuff. So I see $Z_n$ as measurable functions from some probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$. So when i want to show $Z_n=0$ a.s. for large enough $n$, I want to know if there exists $n$ large enough s.t $P(Z_n^{-1}\{0\})=1$. Hence, $\cup_n E_n=\cup_n \{Z_n^{-1}\{0\}\}$. If possible could you describe $E_n$ in terms of pre-images?

Comment: Yes, $E_n$ is $Z_n^{-1}(0)$ But you have not understood what you have to prove.  $P(Z_n)=0$ may be $<1$ for all $n$. What you are asked to prove is $P(Z_n=0 \text { eventually})=1$ i.e. $P(\omega: \exists m : \omega \in E_n \forall n >m)=1$. @JhonDoe

Comment: Oh so what we want to show is that $Z_n\rightarrow 0$ a.s.? I ask because the original statement was "almost surely $Z_n$=0 for all n sufficiently large if $\mu\leq 1$ and $P(\xi_i^m=0)>0$

Comment: Sufficeintly large here does not mean for $n>m$ with  fixed $m$. $m$ can be random. Recalling that $Z_n=0$ implies $Z_{n+1}=0$ (by the very definition of G-W process) ,  the statement $Z_n \to 0$ a.s.  and $Z_n=0$ for all $n$ sufficiently large are one and the same. @JhonDoe

Comment: Ok so I think I get it what we have to show in this case is piecewise convergence to zero and not uniform convergence to zero. Thank you

Comment: Because in this case i had an alternate proof which went as follows: $0=Z*0=\lim\frac{Z_n}{\mu^n}*\mu^n=\lim Z_n$ since we know that $\frac{Z_n}{\mu^n}$ is a convergent martingale a.s. Would this proof work as well?

Comment: Yes, that is also a valid proof. @JhonDoe